# Grammaticality of "I have already asked from him"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, intransitive-verbs

In response to a question, I have to answer.

An example:

> A: Hello B, can I go?
>   B: Ask C first.
>   A: I have already asked from C.

Is this grammatical?

Comment: No, it's not natural English. "I've already asked him" or "I've already asked for permission from 'xyz'" are the standard responses.

Comment: What @BillFranke said, or another very common response is: A - *I already did.*

Comment: What @Jim said, or in BrE, "I already have."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Why "have"? The question was in the Past Simple Tense, how can you answer in the Present Perfect Tense?

Comment: @Gangnus Because British English does not say "I just did," it says "I just have". British English does not use *did* in that way (except that people are beginning to, via an American influence).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: (So British English now does use _did_ in that way.) I'd say that _I just have_ would be fairly unusual, _I just have done_ far more common, and that _I just did_ has been acceptable usage for the last 50 years at least.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, it doesn't. *Starting to* is not general.

Comment: It is when it rains. In any case, I'd say 'I just did' has been used for quite a long time in the UK, and _is_ general usage.

Comment: Apparently, the question is whether the given sentence is grammatical, whether to use "from" or another preposition or any at all, in *I have already asked ___ C.* I think OP is **not** asking for a better way of stating it.

Comment: It **is** grammatical. The preposition *from* **can** be used, as is **of**, or none at all. As for the idiom, the other answers and comments have offered alternatives.

Comment: When you use *already* in British English, you are supposed to put the verb in the perfect. This rule does not apply in AmE (although you certainly are allowed to).

Comment: @Kris: You are saying that _I have already asked from Colin_ is grammatical? I disagree (as do Bill Franke and ash).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Therefore do not ask from the Lord to lift away the tribulation from you, but ask to receive its blessings. Ask from Him to make the tribulation end with good, and in it to give you patience and strength as well as the benefit that His wisdom intends ..."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Note that I spoke only of grammatical correctness and nothing of the semantics. What *I have already asked from Colin* means may or may not be what the OP intended to.

Comment: First, isn't "may" preferable to "can"? Second, I prefer a simple "I did" or "I have."

Comment: @Kris: You've changed the construction from that given, adding a licensing (albeit in a dated way) complement, in your examples. The OP gives a six-word sentence, which is obviously what we're discussing, and which is ungrammatical.

Comment: "... which ... we are discussing": I wasn't.

Comment: Quotes: 'Apparently, the question is whether the given sentence is grammatical' & 'It is grammatical. The preposition from can be used'. These opinions being open to discussion, and this being a discussion forum, my view is that this is part of a discussion about the said sentence's acceptability.

Answer (score 1):

In British English:

```
I already have
I have already asked C
```

Are both correct.

You could probably also say:

```
I already did
```

You would definitely not say:

```
I did already
```

as that is American English, not British English.

Answer (score 1):

To go straight to the answer, *I have already asked from C* is ungrammatical, because in most contexts *ask* is complemented by an indirect object (C) and not a preposition phrase (from C) to refer to the person asked. It has to be *I have already asked C*.

Comment: "in most contexts" is non-exhaustive, while "ungrammatical" and "has to be" are categorical. I have quoted sentences to the contrary in my comments at OP.

Answer (score 0):

> A: Hello B, can I go?
>   B: Ask C first.

*A* can answer:

> - I have already asked C.
> - I already asked C.
> - I did (already).

But *ask* isn't followed by the preposition *from*. You can ask someone *of* something, i.e.,

> I already asked that of C.

But that is prohibitively formal for conversation.

Comment: Or perhaps *inhibitively* formal? :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up answer to ash's answer: Non native speakers frequently have a prepositional or conceptual usage pattern in their native language that makes them interchange "of" and "from."